# How to make sure my method only asks for a file name one time and adds objects into it

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, filewriter

I have a method in my super class that writes data into a file, and that method is overridden in my subclasses. Problem is at run time I get prompted three different times to create a new file. Here is my code:

```
public class Employee
{
    protected String name;
    protected String employeeNum;
    protected String department;
    protected char type;
    protected BufferedWriter printer;
}  


public void writeData() throws IOException
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the new file for next week");
    String newFile = sc.nextLine();
    printer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile + ".txt"));
    String data= getData();

    printer.write(data);

}

protected String getData()
{
    return name + " " + employeeNum + " " + department + " " + type;
}

public class Commission extends Employee 
{
    private int weeksStart;
    private double baseWeeklySalary;
    private double salesWeekly;
    private double totalSales;
    private double commissionRate;
}  

@Override
protected String getData()
{
    return name + " " + employeeNum + " " + department + " " + type + " " + weeksStart + " " + baseWeeklySalary + " " + salesWeekly + " " + totalSales + " " + commissionRate;
}
```

Assume all relevent construcors are there. I have two other subclasses; Hourly, and Salary that trys to implement the same writeData() method. When I iterate through my ArrayList of employees  and try to writeData(),
 It creates a new file for every type of employee when I need it to create just one

```
Public class PayRoll
{
Private ArrayList < Employee > employees;
public class PayRoll()
{
    employees = new ArrayList Employee > ();
}

public void endOfDay()
{
    for (int I = 0: i < employees.size (): i++)
    {
        employees.get(i).writeData(): 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your `Employee` instance, can you add that?

Comment: Your writeData() methods don't seem to be inside the classes...

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect where I'm trying to call the method from

Answer (score 2):

I'd break this method in to two parts. One part requests a file name from the user, opens it, etc. This part doesn't need to be overridden. The only part that needs to be overridden is the part that generates the data string, which can be placed in a method of its own:

```
public class Employee {
    /* Data members, omitted for brevity's sake */

    public void writeData() throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the new file");
        String newFile = sc.nextLine();
        printer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile + ".txt"));
        String data = getData();
        printer.write(data);
    }

    protected String getData() {
        return name + " " + employeeNum + " " + department + " " + type;
    }
}


public class Commission extends Employee {
    /* Data members, omitted for brevity's sake */

    @Override
    protected String getData() {
        return name + " " + employeeNum + " " + department + " " + type + " " + weeksStart + " " + baseWeeklySalary + " " + salesWeekly + " " + totalSales + " " + commissionRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how to break it down, this was exactly what I needed

Comment: I have a problem here, if I have multiple employees in my ArrayList as noted above, it gets called for each employee. How do I get it to create a single file?

Comment: @MacMcGuy create the file outside the loop and pass it to each `Emploee` object in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Add a static variable isFileCreated, set it to true after creating file, and execute that block only if that variable is false.